# Using tree-dvips with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, trees, dvips

It seems like using `tree-dvips` with `pdflatex` is not very easy. It has been documented in various places in the web.

I wouldn't mind using `latex` and then convert to PDF, but I am actually interested in using some options in my `.tex` file which are available only to `pdflatex`.

Is there a way to make `tree-dvips` and `pdflatex` agree?

What happens right now is that my code compiles, but the elements which are supposed to be printed by `tree-dvips` commands do not appear.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you want, but there are many alternatives to `tree-dvips` which are compatible with `pdflatex`, most notably TikZ (and e.g. `tikz-qtree`). Do you have any particular reason for wanting to use `tree-dvips`? What kind of trees do you need to make?

Comment: As Alan says, there are alternatives to `tree-dvips`. Without some reasoning, it's hard to see why you want to go down this route: that makes the question too localized to me.